# How to access an image from azure blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have uploaded images a,b,c and d, now how do I know what is the location/address of my image b in azure blob storage(I am using c# code).
I know i have a way to get the list of all images stored in container but how should i approach if ask is specific to a particular image.

Any guidance should be helpful.

Comment: At least you should know which container the image b is in, then you can use GetBlockBlobReference method to fetch it.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. If you stored your images, you should know the exact location, since the hierarchy is only `<storage-account>/<container>/<blob>`. As for enumerating contents of a container, there are several questions (and answers) on Stack Overflow that already cover that.

Comment: Thanks to all of you , your comments helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `CloudBlobClient` you can get the primary and secondary location of the blob:

```
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);

var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);

var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

var cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName); // "a/b/c/d" blob names

Uri primaryLocation = cloudBlockBlob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri;
Uri secondaryLocation = cloudBlockBlob.StorageUri.SecondaryUri;
```